# ReactNative, error Failed to install the app

Tags: react-native

I don't know what's going on, I've done several projects and it always gives this error. I run it for the first time and that's it, install some things and connect the application to firebase and when I close everything and try to run it again, it gives this error.
I thought it was because of the limit, but it isn't. I didn't install anything this time, just connected to the firebase android and then closed it, tried to open it to see if it would give the error and it did.

This error appears in the terminal:
[image]

and this one in the problems tab:
[image]

That second error always appears, due to the new nomenclature, I don't know why. I haven't had any problems so far, I have other projects and it works fine

About firebase, I'm using android

My app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Text } from 'react-native';
import UploadScreen from './src/screens/uploadScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
   return (
      <>
        <StatusBar />
        <UploadScreen />
      </>
   );
};

export default App;
```

I also did the android studio emulator cache clearing and it didn't solve

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import UploadScreen from './src/screens/uploadScreen';

const App: () => {
   return (
      <View>
        <StatusBar />
        <UploadScreen />
      </View>
   );
};
```